# Search and replace in multi level item structure with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table (6K records) that goes something like this (totally unsorted):

```
Item    |    Subitem  
--------|---------    
71  |   51  
71  |   51  
53  |   54  
51  |   52  
71a |   51a  
71a |   51a  
53  |   54  
51  |   52  
53  |   54  
53  |   54  
52a |   53a  
52  |   53  
51a |   52a
```

Basically, it is a multilevel items structure, meaning that inside the 7*, there is a 5*, and maybe inside that 5*, there is another 5* and so on;
What I want, is that, everything in the 1st column gets replaced by the first level item, which always begins with 7*.
Which would end up to be something like this;

```
Item    |       Subitem  
--------|---------        
71  |   51  
71  |   51  
71  |   54  
71  |   52  
71a |   51a  
71a |   51a  
71  |   54  
71  |   52  
71  |   54  
71  |   54  
71a |   53a  
71  |   53  
71a |   52a
```

I have the following code but it doesn't seem t work as I get a lot of 5*'s as the first level item

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
  mat_A = Cells(i, 1).Value
  type_A = Left(mat_A, 1)
  mat_B = Cells(i, 2).Value
  type_B = Left(mat_B, 1)

If type_A = 7 Then
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Replace What:=mat_B, Replacement:=mat_A, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End If

Next i
```

Anyone has some advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is just as you describe it:
Change none `71` item to `71` item, then you might be able to use this:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet, rng, cel As Range, lrow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow)
    For Each cel In rng
        If Left(cel.Value, 1) <> "7" Then
            If IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
                cel.Value = 71
            Else
                cel.Value = 71 & Mid(cel.Value, 3, Len(cel.Value) - 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
End With

End Sub
```

This code changes all first 2 characters of all values in `Item` column with `71`.
It is assumed that your data is on `Column A & B`.
Now, if you have other requirements, update your question. :)

Comment: Actually the data is a bit more complex, it has records like these 7M37345000A0
5M37450000AV
7000016274A0
5000010697A0,  So it's not really good to replace the only two digits.

Comment: ah, if you could give an actual before and after look of the data, that would be great.